# How to do performance testing for multiple user using Chrome Dev Tool for angular JS Web Site

Tags: angularjs, jmeter, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

I have developed an Angular JS Web Console. Web Console is basically creating, deleting, retrieving and deleting Users.
I want to do its performance testing using **Chrome Dev Tool** or **Jmeter**

If I use **Jmeter** how can I actually monitor the behavior of web console itself because from Jmeter I can only check the response time of API.

If I use **chrome dev tool** then how can I test it for multiple users against post and get operations.

For Example I have a Scenario that 10 Users are **registering** or **signing in**  at a time. How can I test this behaviour.

```
                                      OR
```

50 Persons are creating or deleting or retrieving a **user** using a form at a time.

```
                                      OR
```

What will be the behavior of web console if 50 users are using web console at a time.

**NOTE:** Web Console is deployed on server. I want to test it locally and on server as well.

Need help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i don't get it. angularjs is runned client side, so one ore 50 users is the same thing for the server. I would test the server side like Node.js or the thing who serve API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server side performance and client-side performance are different beasts so you can break down your performance testing requirements into 2 major parts:

1. Conduct the required load onto your web console using JMeter [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers. Make sure you configure JMeter properly to handle cookies, cache, headers, embedded resources (scripts, styles, images). See [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for comprehensive explanation with regards to how to configure JMeter properly. If you need the requests to be fired in exactly the same moment of time also consider [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)
2. As JMeter neither actually render pages nor executes client-side JavaScript you can check client-side performance using one of below approaches (or any combination)

   - Using [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) software
   - Using aforementioned Chrome Dev Tools
   - Using [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) (which provides Selenium and JMeter integration) so you will be able to measure page rendering time. If necessary you can add custom scripting logic using [Navigation Timing](https://www.w3.org/TR/navigation-timing/) API to get some extended information on page loading events in automated manner

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions bro.